# Can I use the output of a function in another R file?

Tags: r, function

I built a function that retrieves data from an Azure table via a REST API. I sourced the function, so I can reuse it in other R scripts.

The function is as below:

```
Connect_To_Azure_Table(Account, Container, Key)
```

and it returns as an output a table called Azure-table. The very last line of the code in the function is

```
head(Azure_table)
```

In my next script, I'm going to call that function and execute some data transformation.

However, while the function executes (and my Azure_table is previewed), I don't seem to be able to use it in the code to start performing my data transformation. For example, this is the beginning of my ETL function:

```
library(dplyr)
library(vroom)
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)

#Connects to datasource

if(exists("Connect_To_Azure_Table", mode = "function")) {
source("ConnectToAzureTable.R")
}

Account <- "storageaccount"
Container <- "Usage"
Key <- "key"

Connect_To_Azure_Table(Account, Container, Key)

# Performs ETL process

colnames(Azure_table) <- gsub("value.", "", colnames(Azure_table))                # Removes prefix from column headers
```

[image: warning]

Both the function and the table get warning. But while the function executes anyway, the Azure_table throws an error:

```
> # Performs ETL process
> 
> colnames(Azure_table) <- gsub("value.", "", colnames(Azure_table))                # Removes prefix from column headers
Error in is.data.frame(x) : object 'Azure_table' not found
```

What should I be doing to use Azure_table in my script?

Thanks in advance!

~Alienvolm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can ignore the RStudio warnings, they are based on a heuristic, and in this case it’s very imprecise and misleading.

However, there are some errors in your code.

Firstly, you’re only `source`ing the code if the function was already defined. Surely you want to do it the other way round: source the code if the function does *not yet exist*. But furthermore that check is completely redundant: if you haven’t sourced the code which defines the function yet, the function won’t be defined. The existence check is unnecessary and misleading. Remove it:

```
source("ConnectToAzureTable.R")
```

Secondly, when you’re calling the function you’re not assigning its return value to any name. You probably meant to write the following:

```
Azure_table <- Connect_To_Azure_Table(Account, Container, Key)
```

Comment: Hi Konrad, yes, that's how originally my code was written. I modified it because it gave me a similar error in the next chunk of code, and I noticed that removing assigning the output to a variable fixed it. Then when I saved and reopened it it wasn't working anymore. I guess I'll open a new thread for the next error... Thanks for the help!